# biopython test_Tutorial ... FAIL

Tags: python, biopython

I'm fairly new to programming. I'm trying to install biopython on mac os x 10.5.

This is what I did so far. 
 1. installed xcode 
2. installed numpy 
 3. ran these commands in terminal 
 `python setup.py build` 
 `python setup.py test`

test reported back one fail.

```
test_Tutorial ... FAIL
ERROR: Run tutorial doctests.
```

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "test_Tutorial.py", line 152, in test_doctests ValueError: 4 Tutorial doctests failed: test_from_line_05671, test_from_line_06030, test_from_line_06190, test_from_line_06479`

Thanks for any help or advice.

Comment: have you read and followed the [installation guide](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/install/Installation.html)? You may need to install the [XCode Command Line Tools](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/)

Comment: Hello Matt  Thank you for your help.  I think I installed that.  I installed xcode from this [link](https://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?bundleID=20414) Since my operating system is mac os x 10.5

Comment: @Samantha: Installing Xcode does not automatically install the Command Line Tools. The way you do that is different for different Xcode versions—it may be a checkbox in the Xcode installer, a separate installer you download and run, a button in the Preferences inside Xcode, … And the name has also changed over the years (I think the most recent name before CLT was Unix Development Tools). But one thing that hasn't changed is that you have to do _something_ besides just installing Xcode.

Comment: @Samantha: However, I don't think that's your actual problem here, as I don't think you would have gotten that far without the CLT.

Answer (score 1):

That file test_Tutorial.py runs marked examples in the source for the main Biopython Tutorial and Cookbook ( http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html / http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.pdf ) to check the examples work as expected. Internally this uses the same library as Python's doctest examples.

**The fact that test_Tutorial.py failed is *probably* a harmless issue with a couple of examples.**

Which version of Biopython are you using? If this was an official release that failure is unexpected. If it was a snapshot from the git repository then that is unfortunate. If you are curious, you could try this to see more information:

```
$ cd Tests
$ python test_Tutorial.py
```

This kind of issue might be more easily discussed on the Biopython mailing list http://biopython.org/wiki/Mailing_lists

Comment: Hello Peter should I go ahead at this point and continue with installing by using sudo python setup.py install.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hello Peter, I downloaded Biopython the source zip file from the biopython website. Thanks I will try the biopython mailing list.

Comment: Which version did you download (the full filename would tell us)? Maybe continue on the mailing list...

Answer (score -1):

I've found that the easiest way to set up a good programming environment is to use [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org), as it has a great way of ensuring that all dependencies are satisfied when installing things. You'll need to be familiar with Terminal and the command line, though.

1. [Install MacPorts](https://distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/MacPorts-2.1.3-10.5-Leopard.dmg) for OSX 10.5. [Read the documentation](http://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.html) too.
2. Restart.
3. Open Terminal.app and enter `sudo port selfupdate` to make sure the portfile definitions are up to date.
4. Run `sudo port install py27-biopython` to install the latest version of Python 2 (2.7.3), `numpy`, and `biopython`. This will take a while.
5. Run `echo $PATH` and make sure that `/opt/local/bin` and /opt/local/sbin` are at the beginning. They should be.
6. Run `which python` and ensure it returns `/opt/local/bin/python`. If it doesn't, run `sudo port install python_select` and follow its instructions to select your default python version.
7. Hopefully, at this point you can run `python` to enter the interactive interpreter, and `import Bio` won't give any errors.

Good luck!

Comment: Hello Matt,  Thanks I will look into MacPorts.